# C++ class: calling private function in for-loop from public function

Tags: c++, class

Given a range of large numbers

```
candidates=[6541367000, 6541368000)
```

find those can be factorized by only 2 prime numbers.

I wrote a C++ class with:

```
vector<long long>& prime_fac(N)
```

returning a vector of N's prime numbers, and

```
void print2PrimeFactoriation(vector<long long>& candidates)
```

returning only candidate with 2 prime factors.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class primeFactorization {
private:
    //vector<long long> prime_vec;
    long long upper_limit;
    vector<long long> res;

    vector<long long>& prime_fac(long long N) {
        vector<long long> prime_vec;
        if (N < 2) {
            cout << "N=" << N << " cannot be factorized by prime numbers" << endl;
        }
        else {
            upper_limit = (long long)sqrt(N);
            while (N%2 == 0) {
                prime_vec.emplace_back(2);
                N /= 2;
            }
            for (long long prime=3; prime<=upper_limit; prime+=2) {
                while (N%prime == 0) {
                    prime_vec.emplace_back(prime);
                }
            }
            prime_vec.emplace_back(N);
        }
        return prime_vec;
    }

public:
    void print2PrimeFactoriation(vector<long long>& candidates) {
        for (long long candidate : candidates) {
            res = prime_fac(candidate);
            cout << candidate << endl;
            if (res.size() == 2) {
                cout << candidate << " can be factorized by 2 prime numbers (";
                cout << res[0] << ", " << res[1] << ")\n";
            }
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    primeFactorization sol;

    vector<long long> candidates;
    for (long long candidate=6541367001; candidate<6541368000; candidate+=2) {
        candidates.emplace_back(candidate);
    }

    sol.print2PrimeFactoriation(candidates);

    return 0;
}
```

Strangely, I got error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'                                                                                                                      
  what():  std::bad_alloc                                                                                                                                                            
Aborted
```

I even tried to reduce input vector candidates to include only 1 element, but the same error still exists.

What is the bug? What shall I do to fix?
Also, is it the most efficient way to do prime factorization?

Comment: set a breakpoint just after the candidates loop. See what doesn't happen. After you fix that, check out some odd behavior inside the for loop with long long prime. You may need a debugger.

Comment: Could we see your `what()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning reference to a local variable `prime_vec` in the function `vector<long long>& prime_fac(long long N)`.

```
vector<long long>& prime_fac(long long N) {
    vector<long long> prime_vec;
    ...
    ... 
    return prime_vec;
}
```

The lifetime of the local variable `prime_vec` here is limited to the scope of the function. Trying to use it after the scope is exited leads to undefined behavior.

Compilers like [GCC and Clang issue a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/MMnt_Y) when you do this:

```
warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'prime_vec' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
        return prime_vec;
               ^~~~~~~~~
```